# Need Metadata specific to To Procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently interested to know System View/Table In Snowflake which can provide information specific to who has developed Procedure.
Do we have any specific view/table for this in Snowflake.?

Answer (score 0):

There is no view showing who created the procedure/function. You can use the PROCEDURES View to find the time the procedure was created:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/procedures.html

Then you can search for query history to find who run the DDL:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html